# Selecting rows in Pandas/IPython similar to SQL

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ipython

I am new to Pandas and I am stuck at a point. Kindly help me proceed.
I have a table and one of the column is as shown below:

```
categories
-------------
[Bakeries, Food]
[Restaurants]
[Bakeries, Food]
```

I need to select all those rows that contains values as Restaurants or values that is LIKE restaurants (similar to SQL where value like '%restaurant%') from the dataframe.

I checked out various forums and I am unable to find a solution for this.

How can I do this?

LATEST UPDATE:

```
resmdt[resmdt['categories'].str.contains('restaurant')]
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-752afd545e7b> in <module>()
      1 #cond = resm['categories'].str.contains('%Restaurants%',na=False)
----> 2 resmdt[resmdt['categories'].str.contains('restaurant')]

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.pyc in __getitem__(self, key)
   1993         if isinstance(key, (np.ndarray, list)):
   1994             # either boolean or fancy integer index
-> 1995             return self._getitem_array(key)
   1996         elif isinstance(key, DataFrame):
   1997             return self._getitem_frame(key)

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.pyc in _getitem_array(self, key)
   2029             return self.take(indexer, axis=0, convert=False)
   2030         else:
-> 2031             indexer = self.ix._convert_to_indexer(key, axis=1)
   2032             return self.take(indexer, axis=1, convert=True)
   2033 

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.pyc in _convert_to_indexer(self, obj, axis)
    608                 mask = check == -1
    609                 if mask.any():
--> 610                     raise KeyError('%s not in index' % objarr[mask])
    611 
    612                 return indexer

KeyError: '[ nan  nan  nan ...,  nan  nan  nan] not in index'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a column of string values, you can use the `contains` method to view only those rows of your DataFrame `df` which contain the word 'restaurant'.

```
df[df['categories'].str.contains('restaurant', case=False)]
```

The Series string method `contains` accepts a string or regular expression as an argument. The `case` keyword argument asserts whether or not the matching should be case-sensitive.

If the entries of your column are Python lists instead of strings, you might consider converting the entries to strings; Pandas can be somewhat tricky if entries are mutable Python objects (such as lists).

[This page](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.14.0/basics.html#testing-for-strings-that-match-or-contain-a-pattern) of the Pandas docs has more information about string methods.

Comment: Hi, I forgot to mention that the column is part of a dataframe.So will contains still work in that case. And all the values within the column is in this form [restaurants,bar]. So i am assuming its a list. Should i be converting the entire column to strings?